# How to list all the obsolete labels in a VOB

Tags: clearcase

I need a command that could list all the obsolete labels in a VOB.

I tried

```
lstype -kind lbtype -obselete
```

But it lists all the lbtypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could at least limit that list to type from the specifc vob with [`lstype`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm):

```
cleartool lstype -invob \aVob -kind lbtype -obs
```

If that doesn't work, check that you have at least one label which is actually obsolete:

```
cleartool lslock lbtype:aLabel@\aVob
```

Note that `lstype` always list non-obsolete types.
It also lists obsolete ones if you add the `-obsolete` option. See an example at [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21368084)

```
cleartool  lstype -obsolete -kind trtype
2007-12-03     joeuser     trigger type "checkin_trig" (locked)
2007-12-03     joeuser     trigger type "checkout_trig" (obsolete)
```

That means you will have to **grep the output** for "obsolete".
As in:

```
cleartool lstype -obsolete -kind lbtype|grep obsolete
```

Comment: yes, forgot to mention invob
but it still lists all the labels not just that are obselet :-/

Comment: labels the lock status doesnt come in the output.

Comment: @user3437212 trigger was just an example. `cleartool  lstype -obsolete -kind lbtype|grep obs`